# how to get json data from external rest full web service in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the json data from an external rest url(http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3) and display it on my web page in my asp.net mvc application. For that I have written some code i.e.

Controleer---

```
namespace MyMVCApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {       

        string Baseurl = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3";
        public async Task<ActionResult> StateDetails()
        {
            List<State> listStateInfo = new List<State>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(Baseurl);
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var StateResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    listStateInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(StateResponse);

                }  

                return View(listStateInfo);
            }

        }

    }
}

Model----
namespace MyMVCApplication.Models
{
    public class State
    {
        public int ObjectID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public int Black { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }
}
```

While debugging the code getting the error: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 10, position 1" at 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.

Please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you just put that url into chrome, it returns an html page and not json.  It also seems to want you to log in or pass an authentication token.  Do you have either of those? you aren't passing either in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your url with `http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3?f=pjson` to get the json version of the web service